# MVC6 Strange _Layout behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I've created a simple MVC6 site from the empty site template.

Here's my `_Layout`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

And my `Index` page:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello World From a View!</p>
</div>
```

The `Home` controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Now here's the problem: Templating via `_Layout` works as expected if the `@RenderBody()` isn't enclosed in any tags, example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@RenderBody()
```

It also works if it's wrapped in a `div`, but when it's wrapped in `<body` tags the page just doesn't load and is in a state similar to an infinite refresh (it just keeps loading the page indefinitely).

Can anyone shed some light on this? Maybe I'm missing some dependency?

EDIT:

A bit of extra info I've forgot to include: It's running on IIS10.

Comment: you dont have head in your page try including that

Comment: like: 
``<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>   
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It should make no difference. I've tried with the <head> tag, and it still behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with IIS10 and ASP.NET vNext.

When I run it directly through `dnx` it works flawlessly. But when I run it through IIS10 it just hangs.